# How I can sort my data with sort() in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, sorting

I get my data from my API, I have already made my call and I display it.

I would like to order it alphabetically.

I don't understand why my console say : 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sort')'

[image]

Comment: You are trying to sort the data before it is received from the endpoint and stored in your variable. You need to wait for the async call to complete before trying to sort the data

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code in the question as text not an image. Also, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are getting the clubs in one async operation and you launch sort operation immediately and the data didn't arrive yet. You must chain the operation:

```
constructor(...) {
  this.getClubs().subscribe(clubs => {
    this.clubs = clubs;
    this.sortClubs();
  });
}

private getClubs() {
  return this.httpClient.get('...')
}
```